# What does windows do before the login screen while waiting?

Tags: boot, windows-10, ssd

I have the following problem: I have a Win 10 machine (recently upgraded) and it took forever to boot up. I therefore installed a SSD and cloned the boot partition over.

Now the boot consists of these parts:

- BIOS and hardware detection (HDDs and startup of basic hardware)
- Windows logo on black screen and *rotating points*
- Login screen (+ rotating points)
- Desktop loading background programs in taskbar notification area

The machine starts with the SSD much faster in the last two points (about 10 sec totally). This is amazing and just as desired. The first point is fast too and cannot be enhanced further, ok.

The problem is that the second point takes over 80 sec. It seems that the machine is doing "nothing" as no HDD action is done as far as I see. I guess windows is doing something in the background and/or waiting for some sort of response that is timing out.

Can you tell me what could be the issue? How to gather more information where the time is spent?

Comment: Windows Performance Recorder is your friend here.

Comment: I believe that one of the things happening at that stage is loading of device drivers.

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Boot**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1** and click to start. This reoots Windows and captures the boot process. After the reboot let the countdown tick to 0 to capture 2 minutes of activity after boot. Zip the large ETL file into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Answer (score 0):

Windows checks for attached devices and loads thie drivers to RAM. Windows also checks for attached displays and configures their resolution, etc.

Steps to see the real stuff:
1- Open Event Viewer by searching in start menu.
2-In the left pane of the Event Viewer, navigate the folders to Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/Diagnostics-Performance.
3-Expand this entry and double click on Operational (it should be the only thing in this folder) to see a full diagnostic report of your computer's operation.
4-Click Filter Current Log in the pane to the right. In the window that appears, change "" (the text box above the one labeled Task category)  to "100." Click OK to apply the filter. The list in the center pane will now show information about each boot process.
5- Select a specific event to see more information about that particular boot sequence.

As I don't know your system configuration, I can only guide you this much, you need to choose the correct event yourself.

Comment: Does this answer satisfy your question?